# Floating point exception?

Tags: c++, floating-point-exceptions

Very straight forward. The code below is from one of my functions:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numberOfVariables; j++) {
        if ((j % i) == 0 && i != 0) {
            table[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it, I get a floating point exception. Except that I am working with no floating points. So what's happening exactly?

Comment: You are getting it, because you are dividing by zero. `if ((j % i) == 0`, when `j=0`, and `i=0`.

Comment: It is not unusual for some platforms to issue floating-point exceptions in response to arithmetic overflow or division by zero, even if there are no floating-point types involved in calculations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `i` is zero, `j % i` involves division by zero, which is not allowed.

To prevent it, you need to change this:

```
      if ((j % i) == 0 && i != 0) {
```

to this:

```
      if (i != 0 && (j % i) == 0) {
```

(taking advantage of the *short-circuiting* behavior of `&&`: if the left-hand operand evaluates to false, then the right-hand operand will never be evaluated).

Comment: ... or start the loop over `i` from `1` and eliminate the `i != 0` test

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first iteration :

```
if ((j % i) == 0 && i != 0) {
```

`&&` and `||` will always evaluate the left operand first, and the condition will short circuit if the condition turns false.

This means that when `i != 0`, it *will* evaluate `j % i` *first*, and so divide by zero. Note that division by zero is undefined behavior.

You need to replace that line by :

```
if (i != 0 && (j % i) == 0) {
```

This way, when `i == 0`, `(j % i) == 0` will not be evaluated

But instead of doing this check, can't you just directly avoid this case? You can simply iterate `i` from `1` to `m` instead so you can also remove the check:

```
for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
```

Edit: Your runtime claiming you encountered a floating point exception is probably wrong and mistook an arithmetic exception as a divide by zero; or it could be due to a compiler optimization. Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate `(j % i) == 0` for `i=0` in your loop, this is dividing by 0 in the background. Hence the floating point exception.

```
int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numberOfVariables; j++) {
      if (i != 0 && (j % i) == 0 ) {
        table[i][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

At runtime, it will evaluate that `i==0` and **skip the modulo** evaluation.
The way you were doing before was evaluating the modulo before verifying that `i!=0`.